# When did people start using “rod” for “ wrought”?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, meaning-in-context, technical, morphology

I’ve seen many online postings for people claiming to sell “ rod” iron rather than “wrought “ iron items.

Comment: Note that the distinction between the /ɔ/ vowel in _wrought_ and the /a/ vowel in _rod_ [has been lost by most Americans](https://www.google.com/search?q=cot+caught+merger), so only the distinction between the final /t/ and /d/ would remain (unless someone was awfully meticulous about vowel length before voiced stops).

Comment: "What hath God wrought?" When I hear "rod" iron" I think maybe there is some confusion about _rebar_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Note that unlike most other groups with the *cot–caught* merger, speakers from Western Pennsylvania—which ***does*** have that merger and so has lost the roundedness distinction just as much as Los Angeles has—nonetheless ***do not*** have the *lot–cloth* ᴀᴋᴀ *lot–log* split, and so native Pittsburghers actually have a rounded /ɔ/ for all three of the merged *clawed–Claude–clod* set. The Angelenos also make a single homophone lacking any roundedness distinction out of those three, but theirs is very different from the Pittsburghers’ version, having now an unrounded /ɑ/ instead.

Comment: https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/26/rod/

Comment: @HotLicks that link had already been posted three hours earlier by user121863. Please upvote the post if you agree that is the answer.

Comment: @Jonorydajo Did you intend your question to be specific to USA speakers? The cot/caught merger is not as universal among English-speakers as some EL&U posts suggest. And the eggcorn here depends on a cod/caught merger.

Answer (score 2):

***[rod iron](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/26/rod/)***  is just a spelling error:

> Wrought iron has been worked (wrought) by hammering and bending, often into elaborate shapes. It is distinguished from cast iron, where the iron takes on the shape of the mold the molten metal was poured into.

> There is such a thing as “rod iron”—iron shaped into rods—but this is a rare specialized term. ***Most instances of this form are erroneous spellings of “wrought iron,” as are all instances of “rot iron.”***

(Paul Brians, *Common Errors in English Usage and More,* Washington State University)

Comment: The OP  recognises that the term "rod" is an eggcorn, they're asking "when" did people  begin misspelling it.

Answer (score 1):

From the website of [American Iron](http://www.americanironlv.com/index.php/wrought-iron/) :

> Today’s terminology for ornamental iron can be somewhat confusing. What is it? “**Rot iron**”, “**rod iron**” or “**wrought iron**”? The best place to begin is probably with the spelling. It’s actually **wrought** iron. Wrought means “worked”.

Comment: However, according to wikipedia, `rod iron' is a distinct type of wrought iron. This makes the situation rather subtle.

Comment: @anemone Unless you have links to Wikipedia to show this, I an going to disregard it. "Rod Iron" has a redirect link https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rod_iron&redirect=no to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrought_iron (The Catechism of Iron, Or the Merchant and Mechanic's New and Complete Guide ... By Benjamin Legge https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xi60SkjbLEwC&pg=PA27&dq=%22rod+iron%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIh8C2mJnsAhXUSBUIHYeyBrEQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22rod%20iron%22&f=false
has "rod iron" but it is not used as a synonym for "wrought iron")

Comment: Discussed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrought_iron#Types_and_shapes

Comment: The Catechism of Iron, Or the Merchant and Mechanic's New and Complete Guide ... By Benjamin Legge (c.1830, British) https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xi60SkjbLEwC&pg=PA27&dq=%22rod+iron%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIh8C2mJnsAhXUSBUIHYeyBrEQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22rod%20iron%22&f=false
has "rod iron" but it is not used as a synonym for "wrought iron")

Comment: How can you tell then, from the very concise question, whether the sellers meant rod iron or wrought iron?

Comment: The OP  recognises that the term "rod" is an eggcorn, they're asking "when" did people  begin misspelling it.

Comment: I think that the rod/wrought is a result of the **cot/caught** merger (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot%E2%80%93caught_merger) and hence the spelling mistakes.

Comment: @anemone Context.